# SQL query : unique studentid that occur with other studentid in other project for more than 10 times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `project` table which contains columns `studentid`, `projectid`. The students worked in group to complete the project and a students is allowed to participate in more than one project. I wish to query on how many students have partnered up together on 10 or more project.

| studentid | projectid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abx |
| 2 | abx |
| 3 | abx |
| 1 | abn |
| 4 | abn |

How do I do a nested query to find out each unique `studentid` have occurrence with other `studentid` for more than 10 times?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Whhere are you stuck?

Comment: And what DBMS are you asking this for? With SQL questions it is important that we know which DBMS you are using.

Comment: I'm using mysql. I am new to SQL. I am literally stucked everywhere :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First self-join the table in order to get the students that worked together. Then aggregate and count.

In order not to look at the same pair twice (s1/s2 <=> s2/s1), I don't join on s1 <> s2, but on s1 < s2.

```
select t1.studentid, t2.studentid, count(*)
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.projectid = t1.projectid and t2.studentid > t1.studentid
group by t1.studentid, t2.studentid
having count(*) >= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

We do a self-join on project and group by pairs of students.
Where student < student avoids having the same student with themself and the same pairs of students both ways around.
The icing on the cake is a list of projects togehter using group_concat (use string_agg in SQL server.

> ```
> create table project (
> student int,
> project varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> insert into project values
> (1,   'abx'),
> (2,   'abx'),
> (3,   'abx'),
> (4,   'abx'),
> (1,   'abn'),
> (4,   'abn');
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   group_concat(a.project) projects,
>   a.student student_1, 
>   b.student student_2,
>   count(a.project) Number_projects
> from project a
> join project b on a.project = b.project
> where a.student < b.student
> group by
>  a.student,
>  b.student;
> ```

> projects | student_1 | student_2 | Number_projects
> :------- | --------: | --------: | --------------:
> abx      |         1 |         2 |               1
> abx      |         1 |         3 |               1
> abn,abx  |         1 |         4 |               2
> abx      |         2 |         3 |               1
> abx      |         2 |         4 |               1
> abx      |         3 |         4 |               1

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fdd44f5fc3db191a7eac4e9f9f950a3d)*